# Windows App crashes when minimised and then brought back to focus

Tags: vb.net, winforms, graphics

I've got a vb.net Windows form targeting .net 4.7.2 (but this problem seems to occur regardless of the .Net framework version. I've wanted to add a gradient colour to the form using [LinearGradientBrush](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.lineargradientbrush), but since doing that, the app crashes if it is minimised and then brought back into focus.
The error displayed is:

[image: enter link description here]

After some investigation I've found that it only occurs if there's also a textbox on the form. The error does not occur with labels, combo boxes, radio buttons etc. just textboxes.

To replicate this without any extra code, I've created a new Windows Form application, and added a single textbox to the form and the following code (which I copied from some website)

```
    Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Paint
    Dim gradBrush As New LinearGradientBrush(Me.ClientRectangle, Color.Blue, Color.White, LinearGradientMode.BackwardDiagonal)
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(gradBrush, Me.ClientRectangle)
End Sub
```

There is no other code in the application at all.
If I run that, minimize the form, and then bring it back to focus the error occurs.
This is a link to a screen capture of the process occurring: https://www.screencast.com/t/9EFuez3hk.
I've tried various versions of the LinearGradientBrush code that I've found online, and I get the same each time.

Comment: If Me.ClientRectangle.Height = 0 Then Exit Sub

Comment: You need to dispose your brush after use.

Answer (score 1):

```vb
If ClientRectangle.IsEmpty Then
    Return
End If
```

That will abort mission if the rectangle has those properties.

Comment: Even though is not strictly related to the current issue, you could mention that, with this kind custom painting, the OP *should* (*must*, if the Form is resizable) also add `ResizeRedraw = True` in `Public Sub New()`, before `InitializeComponent()` (otherwise the Form is not repainted when it's resized) and, as you have already noted in comments, that Brush **must** be declared with a `Using` statement; it's a very *expensive* Brush.

Comment: brilliant.. thank you.
I'm now declaring the brush with `using` too

Comment: As a note, checking `ClientRectangle.IsEmpty` may not be enough if the Form is resized vertically and the `MinimumSize` is not set to at least `New Size(0, SystemInformation.MinimumWindowSize.Height + 1)` (in this case, `ClientRectangle` cannot be Empty, but the `Height` dimension can be `0`). Or - as Hans Passant mentioned - you verify that `ClientRectangle.Height > 0`